# API Controller does not return User.Identity claims correctly

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core, claims

I have a very simple api controller method that should return the claims of the logged in user. When I debug the application claimsIdentity.Claims shows an array of the claims correctly.

But when I test in swagger or postman, I only get

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:59215/api/v1/GetClaims.
```

API method:

```
    [Route("GetClaims")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Claim>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public IEnumerable<Claim> GetClaims()
    {
        var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        return claimsIdentity.Claims;
    }
```

All the other API methods work fine.

Comment: Are you sure that the api endpoint is http and not https?

Comment: yes @AzharKhorasany, just testing it locally now. Have not added support for https

Comment: Try this: return claimsIdentity?.Claims;

Comment: Thanks, but same result @RicardoPeres

Comment: OK, I thought that perhaps the User.Identity was not a ClaimsIdentity, therefore you'd get a NullReferenceException, and was trying to avoid it.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using. Is it .Net Core or Framework? And Is it Web API 2? What route have you got on your controller?

Comment: netcoreapp2.1 @AzharKhorasany, route is mentioned, "/api/v1/GetClaims"

Comment: Can you try https in postman and issue a local postman certificate. It will ask you for it. Just create one.

Comment: Not really, I just run a local IIS Express server without https in Visual Studio. @AzharKhorasany

Comment: So everything works in debug running in VS, but when you publish to IIS express locally it breaks?

Comment: Visual Studio uses IIS Express while debugging, I can put a breakpoint on the return statement and it says that an array with two elements is returned, but swagger and postman shows nothing. I all looks perfectly fine in VS. @JakeSteffen

Comment: Do you have an authorize attribute on the controller?

Comment: Can you show your complete code including controller and attributes?

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the authentication token when you perform the GET